# Passing doubles returns unknown value C

Tags: c, methods, module, double, division

Been having a hard time wrapping my head around this one.  We have a basic assignment for C.  And it's to handle simple math.  I seem to have no issues passing values to the module but the computed value does not get returned and I can't figure out why.  Here's some snippets from the code.

The declared variables:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main()
 {
    //Variables for building the array:
    int a,b,operator,values;
    int tracker=0;
    int quiz[30];

    //Variables for traversing array:
    int i,x,y,z;
    int k=0;
    int result;
    double division;
    char symbol1;

    //Variable for user input
    int userInput=0;
    double userDivision=0.00;

    //Varia ble for correct Answers:
    int total;

    srand(time(NULL));
```

I then build an array of ints using 1 value to determine what the operator is

```
    //Build Array
    for(a=0; a<10; a++)
    {       
            operator = rand()%(4)+1;
            quiz[tracker]=operator;
            tracker++;
            for(b=0; b<2; b++)
            {       
                    values = rand()%10;
                    if(operator==4 && b==1)
                    {       
                            if(values==0)
                            {       
                                    values = rand()%10+1;
                            }
                    }
                    quiz[tracker]=values;
                    tracker++;
            }
    }
```

Once this is done, we then pull in groups of 3 and present the user with the appropriate math question.  The one I'm having an issue with is of course division.  I've left all the prints in there that I was using to track what was going on as you'll see in the example print out.

```
           if(x==4)
            {
                    division = 0.00;
                    printf("Here is the variable before: %.6f\n\n", division);
                    division =  divide(y,z);
                    printf("Here is the variable after: %.6f\n\n",division);
                    symbol1 = '/';
                    askthatquestion(k/3,symbol1,y,z);
                    scanf("%lf", &userDivision);
                    printf("Here's the user input: %lf\n", userDivision);
                    printf("Here's what we're comparing against: %lf\n", (double)division);
                    if(division==userDivision)
                    {
                            printf("Good job!\n\n");
                            total++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            printf("Try again\n\n");
                    }
```

Here is the corresponding module/method the data is sent to

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 double divide(y,z)
 {
    double param1 = y;
    double param2 = z;

    printf("Here's the values passed %.2f & %.2f\n", param1, param2);
    double result;
    int temp;

    result = ((double)y/(double)z);
    printf("Here's Step 1: %.6f\n", result);

    result = result+.005;
    printf("Here's Step 2: %.6f\n", result);

    result = result *100;
    printf("Here's Step 3: %.6f\n", result);

    temp = result;
    printf("Here it is as an int: %d\n", temp);

    result = (double) temp/100;

    printf("Here it is rounded to 2 decimal places: %.6f\n", result);
    printf("The result is %f\n", result);

    return result;
 }
```

As you can see I want the result rounded to 2 decimal places and it seems to work.   Here's is the output received;

```
Here is the variable before: 0.000000

Here's the values passed 5.00 & 9.00
Here's Step 1: 0.555556
Here's Step 2: 0.560556
Here's Step 3: 56.055556
Here it is as an int: 56
Here it is rounded to 2 decimal places: 0.560000
The result is 0.560000
Here is the variable after: 515396076.000000

Question 8: Please answer the following:
5 / 9 =
515396076.00
Here's the user input: 515396076.000000
Here's what we're comparing against: 515396076.000000
```

So not sure what to do from here.  Passing INTs works fine but doubles and floats just don't seem to jive well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if(operator=4 && b==1)` you probably mean `if(operator==4 && b==1)`

Comment: `double divide(y,z)` ???

Comment: You really should use a `struct` instead of an array that mixes operators and operands.

Comment: The code you've posted can't be what you're actually running. You're missing a `%` in `printf("Here's the values passed %.2f & .22f\n", param1, param2);`

Comment: `.22f` should be `%.2f`

Comment: Yeah, the .22f\n was a typo when I edited in the window here.  Still very much stumped by this.  I have a feeling it's something simple like not including the right library or casting something a specific way.

Answer (score 1):

Immediate problem I see, without having more deeply digested your code/design:

This line:

```
if(operator=4 && b==1)
```

Should be:

```
if(operator==4 && b==1)
```

As you wrote it, the test always returns "true" and "operator" is manually overwritten to the value "4" ... the assignment of "operator" to "4" makes an intermediate return value of 4 which is not 0 and therefore "true".

No worries about me critising too harshly ... Python is one of the very few languages that do not allow the invalid use of "=" in place of "==" ... even veteran C/Java developers have to watch for this.

More will be reported as I find it, but that may solve the problem.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't explain the problem he's having with the return value of `divide()`.

Comment: Yeah for some reason I only see these typos after posting.  Thanks for the heads up

Comment: The result of this is that the inner loop will only run 1 time instead of 2, it will always replace 0 values with non-zero values, and will only fill in 20 elements of the array instead of all 30.

Comment: @Zardoz Most compilers will warn about them if you enable verbose warnings.

Comment: I updated the two mistypes and same issue is present.